# how to use both Cassandra and MYSQL in a single project?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, cassandra, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use both  Cassandra and **MySQL** in my project. Some data will be saved into Cassandra and some to **Mysql**. I had been using **mySql** for last 1 yr in the same project and now since I'm Expanding it, I want to add **Cassandra DB** also.

My Cassandra Configuration file is as follows.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:META-INF/application.properties"})
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.repository"})

public class CassandraConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

@Bean
public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
    cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("spring.cassandra.contactpoints"));
    cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("spring.cassandra.port")));
    return cluster;
}

@Bean
public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
    return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
}

@Bean
public CassandraConverter converter() {
    return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
}

@Bean
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
    session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("spring.cassandra.keyspace"));
    session.setConverter(converter());
    session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
    return session;

}

@Bean
public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());

}
}
```

My Repository is

`public interface NewRepository extends CassandraRepository<ID>{
    }`

Now I'm trying to save an entity to it using the reposiroty

```
repo.save(entity);
```

where repo is the object for NewRepository.

But it shows InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: unknown Type.

Where am i wrong.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: I think it's easier to help you if you give more of the stacktrace.

Comment: can you tell me what does 

InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: unknown type

means? I kind of figured out one way but i am thrown with this exception.

Comment: Unknown type [class com.antony.subFile] for property [context] in entity [com.antony.file]; only primitive types and Collections or Maps of primitive types are allowed.

This is the Exception Message.!!!!!

Comment: I don't use Spring framework so I'm unfortunately not aware of what this exception means but you could check their documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException.html?is-external=true

Comment: Thanks for your time.